# Opening two applications with single click?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, executable

I want to open firefox with few websites and eclipse with single click of .sh file.

I am trying the following command:

```
eclipse 
firefox http://localhost/wp3.5.2/ http://localhost/wp2/
```

They work well individually, but how to make both of these commands together so i can open firefox and eclipse through my 'work.sh' executable file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `&` at the end of each command:

```
eclipse &
firefox http://localhost/wp3.5.2/ http://localhost/wp2/ &
```

`&` launches the command and the execution continues at next line.